# Auto-pulling corresponding data between sheets?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

So I have a fairly decent excel knowledge but always looking to improve. 
I am currently working on a tool(calculator) to make my job easier.

This is an excel workbook that has multiple tabs where data is fed through different tabs and auto updates other tabs, that part is no issue.

However, in the final tab I quite often have to modify the formula to suit the case needs. This means modifying two rows of formulas to link in with two columns of data from another work sheet in the same excel document.

I was wondering if there is a way for the second row to auto-populate and react to the change from the first row?

For example the formula in the top row reads: `=SUM('4. Calculator'!I2:I4)`

The formula for the second row would then need to read `=SUM('4. Calculator'!K2:K4)`

Manually changing the second row's formula to the above isn't normally an issue but on large calculations this can be time consuming.

Any advice would be appreciated :)

[Row 1 Formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DWga5.png)

[Calculator tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rsigg.png)

Answer (score 0):

So the 4. Calculator tab automatically pulls in data?

Isn't the case of the formula just '=sum(I:I)' etc rather than changing row numbers?

Comment: No, so in the assessment tab, each column in that relates to 2-4 rows in the calculator tab which has to be modified on a case by case basis. So rather than modifying two rows of formula I was just seeing if there was a way for the 2nd row to check with the first row and update automatically? It'll always be the identical formular, just pulling from column K instead of column I.

Many Thanks